# Is it possible to run SikuliX on a host computer and have the script interact with virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, sikuli, vmware-workstation, sikuli-script

Currently running Windows 10 (native) and VMware Workstation 12 Player. I am running various LTS releases of Ubuntu in VMware.

I am wondering if there is way for me to run SikuliX on my main OS, Windows 10, and have the script interact with a virtual machine, running an Ubuntu OS, that I have open.

The quickstart [documentation](http://sikulix.com/quickstart/) on the download site isn't very specific about the limitations of SikuliX on this topic. It simply says that you can't run it on a headless system (which VMware is not), and you need to have a monitor - the only problem is that I have no idea if SikuliX considers VMware to be a legitimate monitor or not.

I am aware of the fact that you can install Sikulix on the virtual machine itself, but this is not preferable as I would have to possibly reconfigure my VM settings to allocate more memory OR just deal with running the script at a slower pace.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, if you run SikuliX on a native host, it is possible to interact with the the interface of the virtual machine the same as running SikuliX on the virtual machine itself.

Now that I think about it, I should have probably tested this out before posting the question, but hey, if anyone has the same question as I do, now you know.

Comment: Have u tried ut in azure devops? Running test in vm via ci/cd